# FindFirstFile API didn't find all the files in a directory

Tags: c++, windows, api, sdk

I have the following code to find a file in my product:

```
destFolder = "c:\\myproduct\\base\\";

//download and unzip whoisactive.zip from some websites to the installation folder of my product
DownloadAndUnzipSql( "http://www.whoisactive.com/whoisactive.zip", destFolder)

WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile(destFolder.c_str(), &ffd);

do {
    if (!(ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
        if ((string(ffd.cFileName).find("whoisactive") != string::npos) && (string(ffd.cFileName).find("sql") != string::npos)){
            MoveFile(ffd.cFileName, sqlFile.c_str());
            log.Debug(__FUNCTION__, "Succeed to rename file.");
            break;
        }
    }
} while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);           

FindClose(hFind);
```

It works very well before, but it can't find the downloaded whoisactive.sql in recently month suddenly. I checked the c:\myproduct\base\, the whoisactive.sql was there, but when I dumped all the files FindFirstFile and FindNextFile returned, the whoisactive.sql wasn't included.

I don't think that it is caused by antivirus software, because no such software is installed on product environment. And I don't think it's permission problem because the whoisactive.sql is download and unziped correctly.

I googled my problem and found the following two articles:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4659a528-dd51-4749-b751-a491bbdf5fa0/findfirstfile-caching?forum=vcgeneral
[Does FindFirstFile/FindNextFile API pair cache results returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100883/does-findfirstfile-findnextfile-api-pair-cache-results-returned)

It seems that FindFirstFile will cache the file list of a directory, so sometimes we may not find new added files. But I don't think this is the root cause either, because it's weird that my code works very well in last year and never failed, and it can't find the whoisactive.sql in recent month suddenly and never works till now. If cache problem is root cause, then why can I always reproduce the problem now? And it's weird that the code can still work in my development environment, but it can't work in product environment.

So I changed my code to the following, then it works in both product and development environment:

```
destFolder = "c:\\myproduct\\base\\";

//download whoisactive.zip from some websites to the installation folder of my product
Download( "http://www.whoisactive.com/whoisactive.zip", destFolder);

//Unzip the whoisactive.zip and get the extracted file list.
string fileList;
Unzip(destFolder+"\\whoisactive.zip", fileList);

for (int i=0; i<fileList.size(); ++i) {
    if (fileList[i].find("sql") != string::npos && fileList[i].find("whoisactive") != string::npos) {
        string srcFile = destFolder+"\\"+fileList[i];
        string dstFile = destFolder+"\\"+sqlFile;

        if (DeleteFile(dstFile.c_str()) == 0)
            log.Debug(__FUNCTION__, "Failed to delete file %s, error code is %d.", dstFile.c_str(), GetLastError());

        if (MoveFile(srcFile.c_str(), dstFile.c_str()) == 0)
            log.Debug(__FUNCTION__, "Failed to rename file %s, error code is %d.", srcFile.c_str(), GetLastError());

        break;
    }
}
```

You can see the change is that I don't use FindFirstFile and FindNextFile in my code anymore, I just extracted the file name from zip file and access the file directly. So can you please tell me why FindFirstFile and FindNextFile can not find the downloaded sql file in my previous code? Thanks.

Comment: You are not checking result of `FindFirstFile`, not using Unicode versions of these functions and modifying target folder while enumerating files.

Comment: In my case FindFirstFile returned a valid handle but FindNextFile still didn't return all the files; All the files don't use unicode file name, and if this problem is about unicode version api, then why can I get other files in the same directory? And I didn't modify the target folder while enumerating, I mofify the folder before enumerating.

Comment: You are modifying folder by calling `MoveFile`. Note that you are passing only file name so it implies that `destFolder` is set a current work dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not searching the contents of the directory at all. You are passing *only* the directory itself as-is (`"c:\\myproduct\\base\\"`) to `FindFirstFile()`, so that is ALL it will find - attributes of the directory itself, nothing else.

To properly enumerate the directory, you need to perform a wildcard search instead. Append `*` or `*.*` to the end of the directory path, eg:

```
destFolder = "c:\\myproduct\\base\\";

//download and unzip whoisactive.zip from some websites to the installation folder of my product
DownloadAndUnzipSql("http://www.whoisactive.com/whoisactive.zip", destFolder);

WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFileA((destFolder + "*.*").c_str(), &ffd);
if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    do {
        if (!(ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)) {
            if (lstrcmpiA(ffd.cFileName, "whoisactive.sql") == 0) {
                if (MoveFileA((destFolder + ffd.cFileName).c_str(), (destFolder + sqlFile).c_str()))
                    log.Debug(__FUNCTION__, "Succeed to rename file.");
                else
                    log.Debug(__FUNCTION__, "Failed to rename file, error code is %d.", GetLastError());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &ffd));

    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
        log.Debug(__FUNCTION__, "Failed to find next file, error code is %d.", GetLastError());
    }

    FindClose(hFind);
}
else if (GetLastError() == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
    log.Debug(__FUNCTION__, "No files found.");
}
else {
    log.Debug(__FUNCTION__, "Failed to find first file, error code is %d.", GetLastError());
}
```

However, since you are only really interested in a specific file, you don't need to use `Find(First|Next)File()` at all. Just call `MoveFile()` unconditionally and let it fail if the file does not exist:

```
destFolder = "c:\\myproduct\\base\\";

//download and unzip whoisactive.zip from some websites to the installation folder of my product
DownloadAndUnzipSql("http://www.whoisactive.com/whoisactive.zip", destFolder);

if (MoveFileA((destFolder + "whoisactive.sql").c_str(), (destFolder + sqlFile).c_str()))
    log.Debug(__FUNCTION__, "Succeed to rename file.");
else
    log.Debug(__FUNCTION__, "Failed to rename file, error code is %d.", GetLastError());
```

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for your answer, but I still can't find the downloaded sql file even if I added "*.*" to the searched directory. And thanks for your second code piece, it works, but I still want to know why my code didn't work.

Comment: @JunGe you need to add `"*.*"` to the path, not `"."`